# When decoding a jpeg how would I reverse chrominance downsampling in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, jpeg, downsampling

Hi trying to make a simple jpeg compressor which also decompresses the image. I use the following code to downsample the chrominance of an image for the first step of jpeg compression.

```
resampler = vision.ChromaResampler;
[Cb, Cr] = resampler(Cb_channel, Cr_channel);
```

the function is part of the computer vision toolbox for matlab.

for example before downsampling:

Y dimensions = 3024 by 4032;
Cb and Cr dimensions = 3024 by 4032

after downsampling:

Y dimensions = 3024 by 4032;
Cb and Cr dimensions = 3024 by 2016

to display the original RGB image after decompression, the dimensions of all 3 Y, Cb and Cr components need to be the same so that I can merge the channels and convert the image back to RGB. I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
Cb_resized = imresize(Cb, [(size(Cb, 1)) (2*size(Cb, 2))]);
Cr_resized = imresize(Cr, [(size(Cr, 1)) (2*size(Cr, 2))]);
```

When I then merge the 3 channels and use imshow() to see the image it looks fine. So is the above method the correct way of reversing the downsampled chrominance when decoding a jpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `imresize` for up-sampling is "almost correct".

Instead of using `imresize`, you better use `vision.ChromaResampler` for up-sampling:

```
up_resampler = vision.ChromaResampler();
up_resampler.Resampling = '4:2:2 to 4:4:4';

[Cb_resized, Cr_resized] = up_resampler(Cb, Cr);
```

The module is design such that `Resampling = '4:2:2 to 4:4:4'` "reverses" the result of `Resampling = '4:4:4 to 4:2:2'`.

---

The `'4:4:4 to 4:2:2'` ChromaResampler uses a convention that displaces the result 0.5 pixels to the right.
(I think shifting by 0.5 pixels supposes to match MPEG-1 codec standard).

The 0.5 displacement is not well documented - I had to build a short test for figuring it out.

As far as I remember, the convention of moving 0.5 a pixel is used by MPEG-1 codec, but not used by MPEG-2 and newer codecs.
I don't think it is used by JPEG, but I am not sure...

Note:
Since the human visual system is not very sensitive to the Chroma resolution, you are probably not going to see the differences if 0.5 displacement is used or not.

---

For getting the same result as `ChromaResampler`, you may use [imwarp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html), with displacement of 1 pixel in the horizontal axis.

Understanding `imwarp` is a little complicated.
I am going to use `imwarp` for demonstrating that 1 pixel displacement, gives the same result as `ChromaResampler`:

The following code sample shows the equivalence:

```
close all

I = imread('peppers.png'); % Read sample image
YUV = rgb2ycbcr(I); % Convert RGB to Y:Cb:Cr
U = YUV(:, :, 2); % Get U color channel
V = YUV(:, :, 3); % Get V color channel

down_resampler = vision.ChromaResampler(); % 4:4:4 to 4:2:2
down_resampler.Resampling = '4:4:4 to 4:2:2';

up_resampler = vision.ChromaResampler(); % 4:2:2 to 4:4:4
up_resampler.Resampling = '4:2:2 to 4:4:4';

% Down-sample U and V using ChromaResampler
[downU, downV] = down_resampler(U, V);

%downU2 = imresize(U, [size(U, 1), size(U, 2)/2]); % Not the same as using imresize
%figure;imshow(downU);figure;imshow(downU2);

% Up-sample downU and downV using ChromaResampler
[upU, upV] = up_resampler(downU, downV);

% Result is not the same as using imresize
%resizedU = imresize(downU, [size(downU, 1), size(downU, 2)*2], 'bilinear');
%resizedV = imresize(downV, [size(downV, 1), size(downV, 2)*2], 'bilinear');

% Use transformation matrix that resize horizontally by x2 and include single pixel horizontal displacement.
tform = affine2d([ 2   0   0
                   0   1   0
                  -1   0   1]);

% Use imwarp instead of imresize (the warp includes horizontal displacement of 1 pixel)
warpU = imwarp(downU, tform, 'bilinear', 'OutputView', imref2d([size(downU, 1), size(downU, 2)*2]));
warpU(:, end) = warpU(:, end-1); % Fill the last column by duplication

%figure;imagesc(double(upU) - double(resizedU));impixelinfo
%figure;imshow(upU);figure;imshow(resizedU);
%figure;imshow(upU);figure;imshow(warpU);

% Show the differences:
figure;imagesc(double(upU) - double(warpU));title('Diff');impixelinfo
max_abs_diff = max(imabsdiff(warpU(:), upU(:)));
disp(['max_abs_diff = ', num2str(max_abs_diff)]); % Maximum absolute differenced is 1 (due to rounding).
```

Note: The `imresize` usage is kept in comments.

---

Note:
The default interpolation method of `imresize` is cubic interpolation, and the default interpolation method of ChromaResampler is linear interpolation.
Cubic interpolation is considered superior, but linear interpolation is commonly used (the visible difference is negligible).

Comment: Thanks, very extensive reply with 2 solutions. I completely overlooked the fact that vision.ChromaResampler wasn't just for downsampling.